# Setup Chrome OS (Hexxeh) in VMWare Player without network

Tags: vmware-player, google-chrome-os

I downloaded Chrome OS Vanilla in vmx format. When I run Chrome OS in VMWare , on chrome the startup screen the third option is for setting up the network since my virtual machine is not connected to a network, I can't go to next step. I want to access system offline - how would I set up ChromeOS to run offline?

Answer (score 10):

You need to add to the **.vmx** file the line

> ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass these startup screen when you have a network connection.
Only on later stage (after the initial 'installation' process) you will be able to open ChromeOS even in cases where you don't have connection.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add to the .vmx file the line
>
> ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"

On OSX this file can be found within the .vmwarevm package (right click, show package contents) that was created in your virtual machine's folder if you convert the Hexxeh download when opening for the first time in VMWare.

This adds an ethernet adapter to ChromeOS which allows you to log-in as normal.